# A left inverse for the comultiplication on a Hopf von Neumann algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, quantum-groups, von-neumann-algebras

**Edit: incorrect claim at end of earlier version; thanks to Matthew Daws for pointing this out in comments.**

$\newcommand{\cM}{{\mathcal M}}\newcommand{\stp}{{\overline{\otimes}}}$The following technical question arose in some work I'm doing, which concerns traces on Banach algebras, but which has wandered into territory that I don't know well.

Let $(\cM,\Delta)$ be a Hopf von Neumann algebra: that is,
 $\cM$ is a von Neumann algebra and $\Delta: \cM\to \cM\stp\cM$ is a coassociative, injective, normal $*$-homomorphism.

> Does there always exist a completely bounded, linear map $T:\cM\stp\cM\to \cM$ such that $T\Delta$ is the identity? If so, can we always choose $T$ to be normal?

This works for <strike>many</strike> several  examples, for instance when $\cM$ is injective as a von Neumann algebra [the image of $\Delta$ is then complemented in $B(H\otimes H)$ by a norm-one projection], <strike>or $\cM$ is a locally compact quantum group in the sense of Kustermans-Vaes [use the fundamental unitary and then slice].</strike> or if the predual $\cM_*$ has a bounded approximate identity for the natural product induced by $\Delta_*$.

Comment: Erm... How do you use the fundamental unitary to slice?  You have that $\Delta(x) = W^*(1\otimes x)W$ and so $W\Delta(x)W^* = 1\otimes x$.  So it would be tempting to use the map $M\overline\otimes M \rightarrow B(H), z\mapsto (\omega\otimes\iota)(WzW^*)$ but I don't see why this lands in $M$??  Or did you have another argument in mind (in which case, I'd love to see it!)

Comment: Argh, you're right - I think I had examples where $\mathcal M$ is injective or $(\mathcal M)_*$ is operator biflat in mind. Will edit accordingly

Comment: You might know this, but if $G$ is an inner amenable locally compact group and you consider the associated Hopf-von Neumann algebra $(\mathscr{L}(G), \Delta)$, then there exists an ucp map $E: \mathscr{L}(G)\bar{\otimes}\mathscr{L}(G) \to \mathscr{L}(G)$ such that $E\circ \Delta= \iota$ and $(E\otimes \iota)\circ(\iota \otimes \Delta)= \Delta\circ E$. In other words, there exists an equivariant version of your desired map.

Comment: @J.DeRo Thanks - I think I did once know something similar (using the language of QSIN groups, I forget the exact connection with inner amenablity in the Paterson-Lau sense). I must confess that the original motivation for my question was a project that got put on hiatus and is now gathering dust, but your comment might prompt me to try and revive it.

Comment: @YemonChoi The comment I mention holds more generally for locally compact quantum groups btw. More concretely, if $\mathbb{G}$ is a lcqg with associated Hopf-von Neumann algebra $(L^\infty(\mathbb{G}), \Delta)$, then the action $\Delta: L^\infty(\mathbb{G})\curvearrowleft \mathbb{G}$ is amenable if and only if $\hat{\mathbb{G}}$ is inner amenable.

Answer (score 2):

This is far from a full answer (but maybe it will inspire other answers).

I think all the cases Yemon gives, we only get a cb map, but we don't get normality.  However, in some special cases, you do get a normal map.

Firstly, if $M=L^\infty(G)$ with $\Delta(f)(s,t) = f(st)$, then define $T_*:L^1(G) \rightarrow L^1(G\times G)$ by
$$T_*(f)(s,t) = f(st) f_0(s),$$
where $f_0\in L^1(G)$ is some fixed, positive function with $\|f_0\|_1=1$.  This is bounded, as
\begin{align} \|T_*(f)\|_1 &= \int_G \int_G |f(st) f_0(s)| \ dt \ ds
= \int_G \int_G |f(ss^{-1}t)| \ dt \ |f_0(s)| \ ds \\
&= \int_G \|f\|_1 |f_0(s)| \ ds = \|f\|_1, \end{align}
using the left-invariance of the Haar measure.
Then the pre-adjoint $\Delta_*:L^1(G\times G)\rightarrow L^1(G)$ is
$$\Delta_*(f)(t) = \int_G f(s,s^{-1}t) \ ds,$$
i.e. convolution (if you set $f=a\otimes b$).  So then
$$\Delta_* T_*(f) (t) = \int_G T_*(f)(s,s^{-1}t) \ ds
= \int_G f(ss^{-1}t) f_0(s) \ ds = f(t).$$
So $\Delta_* T_*$ is the identity, as required.

More generally, and as Yemon alludes to in a comment, if $(M,\Delta)$ is a compact Kac algebra, then it's operator biprojective (see Aristov's paper "Amenability and compact type for Hopf-von Neumann algebras from the homological point of view").  So we can choose $T$ to be cb and normal (and with various $M_*$ module properties).  If we can choose $T$ with these module properties (but not necessarily normal) then $M$ is said to be operator biflat.  For $VN(G)$ this was investigated by Aristov, Runde and Spronk, "Operator biflatness of the Fourier algebra and approximate indicators for subgroups".  It seems to be unknown if $VN(G)$ ever fails to be operator biflat.  Of course, this is a much stronger condition that Yemon asks for.

It seems surprising to me that we can just write down a suitable (normal) map $T$ for $L^\infty(G)$, but that it seems that Yemon's question is open for $VN(G)$.

**Edit (29 Nov):**  (This is technical; I hope I got all the details correct).  Suppose $G$ is a locally compact group such that $VN(G)$ admits a faithful normal trace (I think is true if $G$ is a separable SIN group, for example).  Then let $\varphi$ be the Plancheral weight on $VN(G)$; let $\omega$ be a normal tracial state.  Then $\psi=\varphi\otimes\omega$ is a semifinite trace on $VN(G\times G)=VN(G)\overline\otimes VN(G)$, and for $x\in VN(G)_+$, we have that $$ \psi(\Delta(x)) = \varphi((\iota\otimes\omega)\Delta(x)) = \omega(1) \varphi(x) = \varphi(x) $$ as $\varphi$ is invariant for $\Delta$ (I know this from the quantum group setting; see papers of Kustermans and Vaes).  Let $(\sigma_t)$ be the modular automorphism group for $\varphi$; then $(\sigma_t\otimes\iota)\Delta(x) = \Delta(\sigma_t(x))$ for $x\in VN(G)$, and so as $\omega$ is a trace, we see that $\Delta(VN(G))$ is invariant for the modular automorphism group of $\psi$.  By a theorem of Takesaki there is a normal conditional expectation $\epsilon:VN(G\times G)\rightarrow \Delta(VN(G))$ with $\psi(x) = \psi(\epsilon(x))$ for all $x$ in the definition ideal of $\psi$.

So in particular, this gives a positive answer (even with the "normal") condition in the separable SIN case, say.

Comment: Of course, the formula for $T$ which I wrote down in the $L^\infty(G)$ case _is_ just $(\omega\otimes\iota)W(\cdot)W^*$; it might just be blind luck that this works in the commutative case...

Comment: If $G$ is discrete, $\Delta: VN(G) \to VN(G) \otimes VN(G)$ is a trace preserving normal homomorphism, its image is therefore always complemented by a normal conditional expectation, right? So the question is open in the non-discrete case only? (But perhaps this is contained in the setting of compact Kac algebra, please forgive my ignorance on the subject).

Comment: @Mikael: Yes to all points!  ($VN(G)$ is "compact" in the Kac algebra sense if and only if $G$ is discrete).

Comment: I think that the answer to my question would also be yes if $G$ is almost connected, using the result proved by Connes (in one paragraph using a complicated paper by Dixmier that people don't cite enough, but that's another story) that for such $G$, $VN(G)$ is injective. Does that look right? Of course the operator biflatness question is much harder for such groups...

Comment: Yes, sure-- but that doesn't give a _normal_ map $T$, which was mainly what was bothering me (that, and somehow using that $VN(G)$ is injective seems like a big stick...)

Comment: The update looks promising - I was vaguely thinking that requiring $VN(G)$ to be finite (which I agree should be the same as $G$ being SIN) was the way to go if one wanted to unify the cases of abelian and discrete $G$. Can you relax your assumption slightly to just needing a separating family of finite traces? that would then allow you to drop the word "separable".

Comment: Actually, it seems that one should be able to generalize this to [IN] groups, according to Theorem 4.1 of Forrest-Samei-Spronk http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4361v3 (really the result is contained in calculations from the Ruan-Xu paper) I guess that from the QG perspective one is using not the Plancherel weight, but something cooked up from the [IN] condition

Comment: @Yemon: Ah, very good find!  Will have to explore that.